# How do I reset the keychain in simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator

I've stored some data in the simulator keychain for sensitive data.
Now I must test what happens if that data is not yet present.

But I am unable to reset my simulator's keychain to test that.

I've tried deleting the app from the simulator and then do a reset content and settings. But the keychain data is still present.

**Edit: YES, I HAVE TRIED "RESET CONTENT AND SETTINGS", but that does not work**

Comment: There is an optio in the menu for that: "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings". :)

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way would be to open your simulator and go to:

`"iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings"`
This will reset everything in the simulator and will return it to Default settings.

If you want to do it through code you can do it like this:

```
NSArray *secItemClasses = @[(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                       (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                       (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                       (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                       (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity];
for (id secItemClass in secItemClasses) {
    NSDictionary *spec = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: secItemClass};
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)spec);
}
```

Comment: Actually, "iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings" does NOT do the trick.

Comment: "Reset Content and Settings" is equivalent a device restore, (Which will reset your keychain) if "Reset Content and Settings" doesn't do that, well, that sounds like a bug in the simulator.

Comment: Not sure what Apple has done, but "Reset Content and Settings" doesn't even delete apps from the simulator anymore.....

Comment: What version of simulator are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you don't add a value after app installation?

Comment: Version 8.3 (SimulatorApp-565.9 CoreSimulator-117.15)
Yes, I am sure I don't add values after app install. I am having this issue since Apple uses a different simulator instance per type of simulator (iPad2 sim, iPad retina etc etc all have their own springboard). I think this was introduced with xcode 6...

Comment: I am going to submit a radar issue to Apple for this.

Comment: @P5ycH0 Can't really tell what is going on with your simulator but I can tell you for sure that my Simulator version 8.3 resets the Keychain and returns the "device" to its original state.

Comment: Using Xcode 8.2, _Reset Content and Settings_ wasn't clearing my keychain... until I found an error dialog hiding below the current window: "**Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted**". I was resetting, then immediately running my project again. Now I wait for the reset to complete, then run, and the keychain is always gone.

Comment: Just an update for anyone running across this in 2019: I did Hardware > Erase All Content & Settings and it did indeed clear the keychain.

Answer (score 9):

**Xcode 13.1**

You can erase the keychain data on the simulator from option `Device` -> `Erase All Content and Settings` like the below image.

Just remember, this option will clear all current data on your simulator.

[image]

Hope to help someone!

Answer (score 6):

There is a race condition with resetting contents & settings sometimes not working. If it doesn't work, try again. If it really keeps on not working, quit `Simulator.app`, wait a few seconds, then run `xcrun simctl erase <Device UDID>` from Terminal. You can get the device's UDID by running `xcrun simctl list`.

This race bug should be addressed in the latest Xcode 7 Beta.

Comment: I've submitted a radar issue which was marked as duplicate by Apple.
So they are working on it, or it's already fixed in the next XCode release.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke those in terminal on running device :

```sh
xcrun simctl spawn ${device_udid} launchctl stop com.apple.securityd;
rm -rf ${HOME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/${device_udid}/data/Library/Keychains;
xcrun simctl spawn ${device_udid} launchctl start com.apple.securityd;
```

Comment: Use `xcrun simctl list devices | grep 'Booted'` to get the list of running sims.